# Is there a place to get Microsoft Access Templates for forms/reports?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I was looking for a quick Form/Report template that I can incorporate a current database into by just binding the fields to the specific fields that are in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, it looks like there might be some at [office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com)...

[image: templates.png]

Comment: yeah I saw this not too long ago too, unfortunately their choices are few. Thanks.